# Placement of acronym vs words spelled out

Tags: acronyms

I am confused whether to place the acronym before or after the words are spelled out. For example, the first time this organisation is mentioned, which of these alternatives is more correct:

> The National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA) was established in 1958.

or

> NASA (The National Aeronautics and Space Administration) was established in 1958.

My intuition is that the first seems more correct, but I am not sure. Any ideas? Also, if you could point me to an official style guide or similar which clarifies this, I would be very grateful.

**Edit**:
The website *Chicago manual style online* has a Q&A section where the following is found:

> Q. I work for a technical magazine. I’ve always been taught that when it comes to
> acronyms, the rule is you spell out the words first followed by the acronym in
> parentheses, and then use the acronym for later references in the copy. If there are no
> other mentions of the acronym later in the copy, then you just spell it out without the
> acronym in parentheses. Is this correct? My coworker is debating this with me.
>
> A. Yes, that’s a good system. Sometimes it’s helpful to repeat the full name in later
> chapters as a reminder. Occasionally, too, it makes sense to use the
> acronym first and put the full name in parentheses, if the acronym in
> question is so familiar to your expected audience that it almost goes
> without explication.

Source: http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Abbreviations/faq0009.html

Comment: One minor point - if you choose your second option, *The* should not be capitalised (the abbreviation isn't TNASA).  I would say the general preference is for the first, but don't have a style guide to prove it, hence the comment rather than an answer.

Comment: There are about 700 000 Google hits for "British Broadcasting Corporation (BBC)" and 141 000 for "BBC (British Broadcasting Corporation)"

Comment: Have checked previous posts on this site as well as writersSE before asking here?

Comment: The info in your edit was most helpful. Basically, it depends! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you use an acronym in a document, you should it *after* the words, *between parentheses*). The second sentence is wrong.

It is what is prescribed ; personally, I don't feel it matters, and suppose the reader to be smart enough to understand anyway.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back that up? I don't think I've ever seen any style guides say anything on this subject either way—i should like to see what they do in fact say.

Comment: There are some interesting returns for "NASA  – The North American" on Google. The North American Sommelier Association. The North American Saxophone Alliance. The North American Squirrel Association. NASA (The North American Sqwurl- Muoss Association). I feel that putting the punchline first wouldn't have the same effect. Seriously, it's probable that the Q&A Section is my favourite resource at CMoS. And far more authoritative than a personal preference.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet  You may contact Scribendi, a private firm in Ontario, Canada, specialized in proofreading. (We have no common interest).

Comment: I’m not sure contacting a proofreader will do much good here, since this is a matter of _style guides_, not ‘right and wrong’. Saying that the second sentence is wrong is quite simply wrong. [CMoS 10.3](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch10/ch10_sec003.html) does have _Full Title (FT)_ as the preferred format, but also have examples of the opposite, and as their answer in the Q&A found by the asker shows, the opposite is sometimes the preferred order, even.